# How can I create records that pair to their parents dynamically?

Tags: apex, sobject

I have batch class which inserts records into a number of different objects from the same logic using dynamic code. My records need to be associated to the correct parent records (i.e. Contacts to Accounts).

Currently this is how I would prepare the record and its related Account:

```
Address__c testAdd = new Address__c();
Account accountId = new Account(ExtID__c='112233');
testAdd.AccountReference__r = accountId;
insert testAdd;
```

How can I make this dynamic so I don't have to specify which sObject I am linking it back to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this won't be a complete example, but you could do something like this:

```
Sobject child = childObjType.newSObject();
Sobject parent = parentObjType.newSObject();
parent.put('extidfieldname__c', parentExtId);
child.putSobject('parentlookup__r', parent);
insert child;
```

Note that you must know that the parent exists or you'll get an error, and you must know if it is an insert or update on the child (e.g. upsert won't be allowed for a generic Sobject reference).

Comment: The child I can actually state what the object is, but the parent needs to be somewhat dynamic. The child needs to be upserted, is there anyway around this?

Comment: @DeploymentFailure putSobject should get you where you want to go, then. If you have a concrete child type, you can use upsert.